# laravel 5.6 fetching data from database to view

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel-5

I'm facing an issue on understanding the content of the index function in the controller

I'm trying to get all the posts from my posts table into a view

my index function

```
public function index()
{
    $posts=\App\post::all();
    return view('MainViews.welcome',compact('posts'));
}
```

my view

```
   <div class="row">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
      <div class='col-md-8'>
        <div class="post"></div>
             h3>{{$post->subject}}</h3>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">read it</a>
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
      @endforeach
     </div>
```

I'm getting Undefined variable error and highlighting @foreach

below is error highlighted

```
          <div class="row">
            18.    <?php $__currentLoopData = $posts; $__env->addLoop ($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $posts):  $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
           19.          <div class='col-md-8'>
            20.            <div class="post"></div>
            21.              <h3><?php echo e($posts->subject); ?></h3>
            22.              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">read it</a>
             23.              <p>
             24.              </p>
              25.            </div>
               26.  <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
              27. 
               28.          </div>
                29.<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can simply use like this.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts=DB::select("select * from `users` where `email`='__'");
    return view('MainViews.welcome',['posts'=>$posts]);
}
```

The view

```
   <div class="row">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
     <div class='col-md-8'>
       <div class="post"></div>
         < h3>{{$post->subject}}</h3>`<br>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">read it</a>`<br>
       </div>
     @endforeach
    </div>
```

Comment: also, check the name of the view same in index

Comment: Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\Users\amaar\Desktop\Blog\resources\views\MainViews\welcome.blade.php) @Ajay

Comment: make sure the name of view same in index function.

Comment: also sure that these file included with your index function                                                    <br>  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;